# Mobile menu visibility and invisibility using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bem

I am new to javascript and jquery. In the online course i am doing, we are learning to make our mobile menu appear and disappear by having it add a modifier to the selector element when you click the menu icon (.nav-bar__menu-content to .nav-bar__menu-content--is-visible, for example). When i go to chrome inspect, i can see that the js is working because the modifier is being added and then removed when i click on the menu icon. However, the actual content is not appearing and then disappearing. I'm not sure why? There doesn't seem to be a specificity issue and i am pretty sure i am targeting the proper selector. Any help is appreciated and also sorry if my language is confusing. I'm new to this.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNyuy.png)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41836142/edit) your code into the question, not just a picture of it

Comment: did you write the CSS to hide and show based on the class?